# "Webpack imported module userClerk is not a function" Error

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, clerk

I am working on a Next js 14 project using Clerk for auth.
in my Navbar I am using `useUser()` normally as in this code (This is the UserMenu.tsx component imported in NavBar.tsx component ):

```
import * as React from "react";
import {useClerk, useUser} from "@clerk/nextjs";

export function UserMenu() {
const { isSignedIn, user, isLoaded } = useUser();
let avatar = null;
if (!isLoaded) {
    avatar = null;
}
if (isSignedIn && user && user.imageUrl) {
    avatar = user.imageUrl;
}
return (
    ...... \\CODE
);
}
```

That code does the job correctly, I am trying to the same in `app\home\page.tsx`

```
import {useClerk, useUser} from "@clerk/nextjs";

const Page = async () => {
const { isSignedIn, user, isLoaded } = useUser();
return (
   // CODE
);
};
export default Page;
```

But this time it doesnt work, I get this error
[image]

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: (0 , _clerk_nextjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.useUser) is not a function
```

Knowing that I am correctly wrapping my app arround the `<ClerkProvider>`

[image]

I need some help please,
Thank you.

Comment: r u on a client component or server component?

Comment: oh I just noticed the difference here, the navbar is client component and the home is a server component ..

Comment: I need to keep the home\page.tsx as a server component also I ll neet to get user.session id in that component ... is there an alternative way to do that ?

Comment: you can use hooks only at client components. you have to add `use client` directive on top of the component if you are using hook

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too... The solution is add "use client" at the top.

```js
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import { useClerk, useUser } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export function UserMenu() {
  const { isSignedIn, user, isLoaded } = useUser();
  let avatar = null;

  if (!isLoaded) {
    avatar = null;
  }

  if (isSignedIn && user && user.imageUrl) {
    avatar = user.imageUrl;
  }

  return (
    // ...... CODE
  );
}
```